# Paging toolbar list all rows from store in Extjs2

Tags: extjs

I am using PaggingToolbar to support paging at a gridPanel. Problem is, every page displays all the records from the store. Can anyone help to solve the issue. Code details as follows:

I have a store with xmlReader

```
  var store = new Ext.data.Store( {
            url :'urltoreturnxml',
            reader :new Ext.data.XmlReader( {
                record :'Book',
                id :'@id',
                totalRecords :'@total'
            }, [{
                name :'book_id',
                mapping :'@id'
            }, {
                name :'price',
                mapping :'@price'
            } ])
        });
```

And a grid panel

```
  var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel( {
            store :store,
            viewConfig : {
                forceFit :true
            },
            loadMask: true,
            width : 685,
            height : 200,
            columns : [
            //       column names
            ],
            bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({ // paging bar on the bottom
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
                emptyMsg: 'error'
            }),
            sm :new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel( {
                singleSelect :true
            }),
            listeners : {
             //some code
            }

        });
```

I load store as follows

```
   store.load({ params: {
                         start: 0,
                         limit: 20
                         },
               callback : function(r, options, success) {
         // callback function
            }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Problem is, every page displays all the records from the store." - Are you saying that there is no effect of limit:20 which you are sending to the server and all the records are being returned by the server everytime & getting displayed? Well, then you need to visit your server side code again and check it. Else, if possible, please share some online demo of what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to return the amount of records it is asked to serve.
If you return all the records regardless of your client request you will get all the results in the gird.